# Exception in fetching data from json file

Tags: jquery, json, jqxgrid

I am using following code :

```
   var source1 =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'x' },
                { name: 'y' }
            ],
            url: '..\sampledata\status.txt'
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1, { async: false, autoBind: true, loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error loading "' + source1.url + '" : ' + error); } });
```

its throwing this exception :

```
  [Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:1397/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 8382"  data: no]
```

for jquery-1.7.1.js it's showing same exception but in line 8068

I am not able to get is this error related to jqx dataAdapter or is it from .js file .

my status.txt contains json data

```
   {
"StatusTable": [
    {
        "x": "quickydata",
        "y": "137"
    },
    {
        "x": "somestuff",
        "y": "1210"
    }
 ]
}
```

Looking for some solution/suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
   var source1 =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'x' },
                { name: 'y' }
            ],
            root: "StatusTable",
            url: '..\sampledata\status.txt'
        };
```